# Remove account on a single Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, user-accounts

How I can remove myself from some Stack Exchange sites, but keep my profile? (For example, I subscribed to some sites just for curiosity; I just browsed without posting or replying.)

I found a delete option but I am afraid to click!

Would it be possible also to unsubscribe from sites where I have been active?

Comment: You don't subscribe, you create new associated account. And yes, it's safe to click the "delete" button. Your other accounts won't be affected by any means.

Comment: I clicked, and I am still here! :)

Comment: Very true, that's a relief! :)

Comment: For completeness, here is a  related question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting an account on one site has no effect on any of the other sites. Even if you delete the account that reached 200 rep and all the other accounts have less than 200 rep, you won't lose the association bonus on those accounts.

If you have no activity on a site then you can delete the profile yourself by using the "delete" link on your profile.

If you have some activity - specifically voting and/or posting more than once (see the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) - then you must contact the team via the "contact us" form linked to in the footer of all pages to get the account deleted.