# Does removing a login at one Stack Exchange site remove that login at all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, login

If I go to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and click on my name to access my profile, I see a "my logins" link.  When I click on it, the "My Logins" popup appears:

```
My Logins
Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts

Stack Exchange
address1@domain1.com  change password
address2@domain2.com  change password

add more logins...
```

However, there is not a `remove` link next to the `change password` link.  This is *different* than the screen shown in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/302968) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers).

But now, if I go to a *particular* Stack Exchange site -- for example, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) -- and then click on my name, I am taken to my Stack Overflow profile.  Then, if I go to **Edit Profile & Settings > My Logins**, I am taken to a *different* "My Logins" page:

```
My Logins
Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts

Stack Exchange
address1@domain1.com  change password  remove
address2@domain2.com  change password  remove

add more logins...
```

So, now, here there is a `remove` link.

**My question is, if I click the `remove` link here, on Stack Overflow, next to one of my logins, will that login be removed on all of the other particular Stack Exchange sites?**  (I am a member of Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, Computational Science Stack Exchange, etc.)

I am hoping that I don't have to remove that login from *each* individual site of which I am a member.  It confuses me that the `remove` links do ***not*** appear on the "My Logins" page on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, changing your login methods on one site will change your login methods for all sites you currently use.

Users are not able to add or remove logins at all on stackexchange.com because it is not an actual site, but more of a hub for all the sites you use (you can't even edit your profile there - it auto-updates from your most active site). The "my logins" page there is simply a display of which ones you have available. There is very little that you can do on stackexchange.com itself other than get network-wide information.

Comment: Thanks so much. After I saw your answer, I found [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235303/302968) to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235301/remove-account-on-a-single-stack-exchange-site).  What does it mean when it says, "Deleting an account on one site has no effect on any of the other sites (unless it's the one site where you have the 200+ points that give you eligibility for the association bonus)."?  I am a member of a few Stack Exchange sites where I have less than 200 reputation points.

Comment: Deleting a profile will only delete the profile on that particular site, and not delete your profile from any other sites. Deleting a *login credential* will delete the login credential across all sites.